# How to change the "svjour3" class of "Springer" to use 12pt as font size?

Tags: fontsize, sv-classes

I am writing the draft of my paper in the [`svjour3`](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour3/global.zip) class of [Springer](http://www.springeropen.com/authors/tex).
It seems that the default font size is 10.
I would like to change it to 12.
I spent a lot of time to make some changes in "svjour3" or added some commands in my file.
None of them work!
Please help to to get rid of 10pt!

Comment: Do you plan to submit your draft to Springer? If yes, font size changes (or other changes to the template) might not be accepted.

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to change the style of a publisher class. By design they are designed _not_ to have many author options because they are designed to force the publisher house style. Either use the class as is or use a generic class designed for author options such as article.

Comment: My problem with the template of Springer is, at least, twofold: 1) Its font size is too small for the "review process". I belive that it may have negative effect on the mind of a reviewer! 2) The default margins of the template seems to be ridiculous. Its margins in left is around 1", while on the right is around 2"! I do not know what the they do in their final process on the file, but the template they have posted on their website is a disaster!

Comment: Unfortunately even thought the decisions of Springer seem ridiculous to you and a disaster, you are bound by them. Do you have to use their class for submitting the paper to the reviewer?

Answer (score 2):

The `svjour3.cls` doesn't define any other font option than `10pt`.

So there's no real way to override the decision made by the class developers. You might add

```
\usepackage[12pt]{extsizes}
```

paying the price of an annoying warning and risking bad output in some situations.

Answer (score -1):

you can use geometry package to change margins.

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paperheight = 11in,
    paperwidth  = 8.5in,
    left   = 1.0in,
    right  = 1.0in,
    top    = 1.0in,
    bottom = 1.0in
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The question is about the font size, not the type block size.